# How to resize a table with LaTex?

Tags: latex, pdflatex

I am writing a document with Latex and I have a table inside. It must be clear and readable in the PDF. Now it appear very small and I can't edit his size.

```
\begin{table}[h]
\centering

\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}

\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{\Huge Sommaire de cas d’utilisation « commencer consultation »}}\\

\hline
\textbf{\Huge Titre} & \Huge Commencer consultation.\\

\hline
\textbf{\Huge But}  & \Huge Permettre au médecin de sauvegarder tous les informations nécessaires au cours d’une consultation.\\
\hline

\multirow{\textbf{\Huge Résumé}} & \Huge {Le médecin sauvegarde la consultation avec un patient (ajout d’examen clinique, demande des  analyses et prescription des ordonnances).} \\
%\hline

&\Huge pour accéder au site  la vérification de leurs documents .\\
\hline

\textbf{\LARGE Acteur} & \Huge Médecin \\
\hline

\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{\Huge Description des enchainements }}\\
\hline

\textbf{\Huge Pré-condition}  & \textbf{\Huge Post-condition}\\
\hline

\Huge L’authentification du médecin. &\Huge Le médecin a sauvegardé la consultation. \\
\hline

\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{\Huge Scenario nominal}}\\
\hline

\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\Huge 1. Le médecin accède à son page d’accueil.}\\
%\hline

\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\Huge 2. Le médecin accède à la liste des rendez-vous.}\\
%\hline

\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\Huge 3. Le système affiche la liste des rendez-vous.}\\
%\hline

\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\Huge 4. Le médecin clique sur « commencer consultation ».}\\

%\hline

\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\Huge 5. Le système affiche l’interface de consultation.}\\

%\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\Huge 6. Le médecin peut ajouter des examens cliniques.}\\
%\hline

\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\Huge 7. Le médecin peut demander des analyses.}\\
%\hline

\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\Huge 8. Le médecin peut prescrire une ordonnance.}\\
%\hline

\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\Huge 9. Le médecin clique sur « Enregistrer ».}\\
%\hline

\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\Huge 10. Le système enregistre les informations relatives dans la base des données.}\\
%\hline

\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\Huge 11. Si les informations sont enregistrés avec succès le système redirige le médecin à la liste des  rendez-vous.}\\
%\hline
\hline

\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{\Huge Scenario d’échec}}\\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\Huge 1. Erreur d'authentification.}\\
%\hline

\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\Huge 2. Champs obligatoires vides et/ou non valides.}\\
%\hline

\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\Huge - Le système affiche un message d’erreur.}\\
%\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\Huge - Le scenario reprend de 4.}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}}

\caption{ Table d ‘analyse du cas d’utilisation « commencer consultation » }
\end{table}
```

Comment: You might have better luck with this at https://tex.stackexchange.com

Comment: Are you sure a table is the best way to present that text?

Comment: Please add your preamble...!